# Remote LogOn with WCF and C#

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, integration-testing, winlogon

Is there any way to log on to a Windows machine using WCF and C#? I am creating a Test Harness and it will needed to remotely logon a Windows user.

So far we have not been able to do it successfully as once the user has been log off from the machine, self-hosted WCF is shut down.

Comment: there is no answer from the service on the machine?  how is the service hosted?

Comment: You run the self-hosted WCF under IIS? Try hosting your WCF service in a Windows service. Then it can start whenever the server starts, even if there are no interactive users.

Comment: @Roy self-hosted is basically a Console App, not IIS-hosted. Tnx for the Win Service suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

your problem is that you are hosting the service as a console app.  When the user logs off, the app stops.

Host your service in a windows service, which will enable it to start and run without a user being logged on.

[MSDN on hosting in a windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

as a tip, in the OnStart method add the following line:

```
Debugger.Launch();
```

and a using statement:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

if you have problems with the service starting and immediately stopping.  This should allow you to attach a debugger to the service as it is starting to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using supplied credentials on the web end you could try logging in via WMI? but, it does depend what you intend to do to the remote machines - other option would be a client on the remote machines

Comment: can you pls explain a bit more in details: is there remote WMI logon? What do you mean by _a client on the remote machines_ and how I can communicate with it when the PC is logged off?

Comment: WMI is a method of connecting to remote machines and performing actions - a quick google has plenty of examples - however to do pretty much anything you would need to provide it credentials - eg, get a username + password eg from your website.